# Archive of QNX's use messages?

Tags: man, qnx

**Context**

I do not know all standard linux/unix commands, so I need manpages.

I found QNX's manuals (invoked by "use [command name]") terse; I prefer them to linux manpages.

I can get them from QNX with shell script, but I need to have QNX installed and it seems system does not have "use" for all commands.

**Question**

Is there archive of QNX's use messages on internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found them here: http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/dv/hats/cats/stations/qnxman/

Answer (score 1):

There is official QNX documentation for utilities here:

http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/utilities

For example, the manual page on `fs-cifs`:

http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/utilities/f/fs-cifs.html

Several commands (i.e. `sshd`) come from NetBSD, so their manual pages may provide more information:

http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?sshd++NetBSD-5.0